# Capturar en una variable el valor que se obtiene de un innerhtml, ára giardar en una base de datos mysql

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

```javascript
$(document).ready(function () {
 
    let $id_TipoProducto = document.getElementById('id_TipoProducto')
 
    function cargarOrigenProductos() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../php/select.php',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                const id_TipoProductos = JSON.parse(response);
                let template = '<option  selected disabled >-- Seleccione --</option>'
                id_TipoProductos.forEach(id_TipoProducto => {
                    template += `<option value = "${id_TipoProducto.CodProducto}">${id_TipoProducto.TipoProducto}</option>`;
                })

                $id_TipoProducto.innerHTML = template;
            }
        })
    }
    cargarOrigenProductos()
```

3.que a su vez obtiene los datos al consultar un archivo php:

```php
    <?php
        function obtenerOrigenProductos() {
          require 'conectar1.php';
            $query = "SELECT id_TipoProducto, Tipo_Producto FROM tipo_producto";
            $result = mysqli_query( $con, $query );
            $json = array();
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $json[] = array(
                  'CodProducto' => $row['id_TipoProducto'],
                  'TipoProducto' => $row['Tipo_Producto'],
                );
            }
            $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
            echo $jsonstring;
        }
```

4. el problema es que me pinta el resultado en el formulario principal del **select** `id="id_TipoProducto"`, pero no logro captiurar el valor que se muestra del `innerhtml` para guardar en una base de datos mysql

Comment: No entiendo esta frase: *pero no logro captiurar el valor que se muestra del innerhtml para guardar en una base de datos mysql*... Tampoco vemos lo que es `id_TipoProducto` en tu HTML, aunque entiendo que es un **select** con su **name=** correspondiente que luego envias a alguna parte con un submit de un formulario, y es allí donde no te funciona.  Eso es lo que me ha parecido entender, y si es así entonces debes poner tanto el HTML del select como el PHP que recibe esos datos del formulario para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: hola amigo, es un formulario donde traigo tres valores a traves de tres select anidados, obtengo los valores en un archivo js y los muestro a traves de un innerhtml  en el respectivo select, pero no puedo obtener el valor que pinta el innerhtml para guardarlo en un varible y enviarlo a la base de datos, me dices si me  pude hacer entender o a que correo te puedo contactar para que por favor me orientes, muchas gracias

Comment: Si todo eso va a un formulario, tan solo debes poner un atributo "name=" a cada select donde vayan esos options y luego, en el script que reciba PHP que reciba el formulario, los recuperas con $_POST o con $_GET, segun uses un method="POST" o method="GET" en el **action** del formulario. No tiene mas secreto y no necesitas capturar el innerHTML en javascript para ello.

Comment: ok, mki amigo lo voy a intemntar de esta manera, te agradezco mucho.

Comment: listomi amigo logre mostrar el primer valor te agradezco mucho

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro por ti :-)  Saludos!

Comment: buena noche, amigo por favor mepuedes ayudar nuevamente: desde este codifo estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen que la ruta esta almacenada en una bd, pero solo logro que me imprima la ruta, se que debo añadir uan etiqueta <img src = ""> pero no logro qu eme funcione.

Comment: <td colspan = 2 align='center' border = '1' style = padding: 10px; width: 50px; height: 25px; >".resaltar_frase($row['Fotografia'], $_POST['buscar'])." </td>

Comment: no se que es **resaltar_frase** ni lo que hace... pero supongo que lo que quieres es esto: `<td colspan = 2 align='center' border = '1' style = padding: 10px; width: 50px; height: 25px; ><img src="'.$row['Fotografia'].'">".resaltar_frase($row['Fotografia'], $_POST['buscar'])." </td>`